# Magento2. KnockoutJs. Define Scope and call function on the same html node

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, data-bind

I have a very simple Component

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.notificationCounts = customerData.get('notification_counts');
        }
    });
});
```

I want to conditionally display an html element based on whether I have or not have any notifications.

I managed to do so with the following template:

```
<span data-bind="scope: 'notificationCounts'">
    <span id="some-id"data-bind="visible: notificationCounts().count">
         ... more content here ...
    </span>
</span>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
    
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "notificationCounts": {
                        "component": "Vendor_Module/path/to/js"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

However, I would like to get rid of the first wrapping span.
This is how I changed the template (only relevant parts)

```
    <span id="some-id" data-bind="scope: 'notificationCounts', visible: notificationCounts().count">
             ... more content here ...
    </span>
```

But now I get the following console error:

```
Unable to process binding "visible: function(){return notificationCounts().count }
```

Any idea how I can get rid of the extra wrapping span? Maybe some ko directive I'm missing.

Any hints are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are all the ways you can define the scope in a template:

```
<!-- as an attribute -->
<div ko-scope="'name.of.component'"></div>

<!-- in a standard KO form -->
<div data-bind="scope: 'name.of.component'"></div>

<!-- without an extra container node -->
<scope args="'name.of.component'"></scope>

<!-- as a virtual element -->
<!-- ko scope: name.of.component --><!-- /ko -->
```

source: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/concepts/knockout-bindings/

So for the code in the question we are going to use a virtual element to achieve our goal:

```
<!-- ko scope: 'notificationCounts' -->
    <span id="some-id" data-bind="visible: notificationCounts().count">
                 ... more content here ...
    </span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

That's it.